# Build call hierarchy using Microsoft Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am trying to statically build the call hierarchy of a C# solution, or in other words try to figure out which method calls are made by every method in the solution.

I have slightly modified a code snippet from another question but it doesn't quite cut it:

- [Can I get function caller/callee information from Roslyn?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/85a816cb-e931-4b49-893a-abbbf38c7a38/can-i-get-function-callercallee-information-from-roslyn)

The chain is broken whenever a base class method is called and that method in turn calls an abstract or virtual method implemented in a sub-class.

```
var syntaxTree = SyntaxTree.ParseText(Code);
var compilation = Compilation.Create("name").AddSyntaxTrees(syntaxTree);
var semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(syntaxTree);
var methods = syntaxTree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>();
foreach (var method in methods)
{
    var invocations = method.DescendantNodes().OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>();
    foreach (var syntax in invocations)
        Debug.WriteLine(semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(method) + " calls method " + 
            semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(syntax).Symbol);
}
```

Here is some example code to illustrate the problem. Base class method Bar makes a call to the abstract method Baz implemented in C2.

```
class Program2
{
    void Main()
    {
        new C2().Bar();
    }
}

abstract class C1
{
    public void Bar()
    {
        Baz();
    }

    public abstract void Baz();
}

class C2 : C1
{
    public override void Baz() { }
}
```

However when running the top code snippet on the example code it thinks the call is to C1.Baz():

```
Program2.Main() calls method C1.Bar() 
C1.Bar() calls method C1.Baz()
```

How can we use the semantic model to figure out that it is actually C2.Baz() that will execute?

Comment: You do realize that static analysis of which override of virtual method will be executed won't work most of the time, right?

Comment: You seem to be assuming that you have the source code to all methods in the call chain, which might not be true. Derived classes might be located in other assemblies. Your program might call into the .NET Framework, that calls back into your program (e.g. you pass an IComparer to the constructor of a SortedList - how is your routine supposed to see that the Compare method will be called?) You might get somewhat better results parsing IL directly, such as with Cecil. And even then, you are asking for a variation of the halting problem, which is known to be unsolvable.

Comment: To add insult to injury, you do realize that property access and overloaded operators are also method calls behind the scene? Furthermore, you will likely miss calls to Dispose() through foreach() and using().

Comment: _You seem to be assuming that you have the source code to all methods in the call chain, which might not be true._  The code the the OP cares about analyzing the call tree for is very likely "just my code"